# overriding django formset initial data dynamically

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework, python-3.5, django-1.8

Ok im new to django 
So ive got a situation where i want a formset to have dynamic initial data

So basically here is what im looking  for.
each form in the formset to have a different UserID 
and a set of groups permission which they can choose from based from the initial data

here is my form

```
class assignGroupPermissionToUser(forms.ModelForm):
    UserID = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None)
    Groups = forms.ModelMultipleCHoiceField(queryset=None, widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Groups")
class Meta:
    model=User
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    Userid = kwargs.pop("UserID")
    self.fields['UserID'].queryset =User.objects.get(UserID=Userid)
    Permissions = kwargs.pop("Groups")
    listofPermission = None
    for each perm in permission:
        listofPermission |= Permissions.objects.filter(GroupID=perm)
    self.fields['Groups'].queryset = listofPermission
```

the data i wanna pass is built into a list like so

it is called 
completeList

```
> completeList =[['13452',{'group1':'Admin','group2':'FrontDesk'}],['3532','group1':'Supervisors','group2':'ReadOnly;}]]
```

where the first value in each nested loop is the UserID, and the dictionary is the groups  they can choose from.

override method in View.py

```
....
form = assignGroupPermissionToUser()
assignment = formset_factory(form,extra=0)
formset = [ assignment.__init__(completeList[x][0],completeList[x][1]) for x in range(len(completeList))]
```

then i get an error that str object has no 'is_bound' field line 58 of formset.py

im trytin to get this data to show up on each form and based on the user
it will be all different but everything i try to override it fails for initial form so here i am stuck

note that the Group attribute in the modelform has a widget which is used in the admin section to filter from multiple choices.

settings
Django= 1.8
python 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i erased all this code and just did two loops like so

```
formset = assignments(initial=[{'UserID': listofUserID[x] } for x in range(len(completeList))])
#then
for form in formset:
    form.fields['permissions'].queryset = querysetiwant
```